# What is the recommended size of dataset for optimized broadcast joins?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am being provided with a large data-set in JSON text files, one JSON object per row.  One of the fields I need to parse/convert is an epoch time-stamp (to a readable date).

So, step one of processing the data is to load it and parse it.  If I do an rdd.map operation, I can either:

- Create a simple date format object inside the map (will happen for every record).
- Create a simple date format object and broadcast it, creating it only once.

I don't quite understand which of these is better for an object of this size (I usually use broadcast for somewhat sizeable collections calculated on the driver).

Can anyone help me understand which option is better and why?

Answer (score 0):

Your question *seems* to suggest that you want to use the dataset (you wonder whether it could be a good candidate for broadcasting) to join it with some other dataset.

If so, I think you may want to read my Mastering Apache Spark 2 gitbook about [Broadcast Joins (aka Map-Side Joins)](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-sql-joins-broadcast.html):

> Spark SQL uses **broadcast join** (aka **broadcast hash join**) instead of hash join to optimize join queries when the size of one side data is below `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`.

You can therefore fine-tune the broadcast join using `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` property that is `10M` by default.

Quoting [Broadcast Variables](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables):

> Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a read-only variable cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks. They can be used, for example, to give every node a copy of a large input dataset in an efficient manner. Spark also attempts to distribute broadcast variables using efficient broadcast algorithms to reduce communication cost.

That does not say about how big your dataset should be that would allow for effective broadcast. It does depend on the amount of memory for your Spark application. If you have a *beefy* cluster with a plenty of RAM, any size would work. It's a tradeoff between network bandwidth and the available RAM.

My recommendation would be to calculate the required memory for a Spark application and see how much is left for broadcast variables (per executor). I'd then calculate the size of a dataset for broadcast and see whether it'd fit. If so, I'd give broadcast a shot and monitor performance. If it worked fine, I'd go live.

Comment: What do you think would be a reasonable starting value, if one was looking to maximize broadcast joins? Would allocating up to 10-20% executor memory be a solid starting point, or would it be closer to 1-2%. Obviously the final number depends on the interconnect, dataset, overhead, etc - but those 10M appear to be a very conservative default.

Comment: The reasonable starting value is...well...10MB. I think 10-20% of executor memory seems reasonable too. That however requires testing with your dataset and application so hard to say how much is the right value.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to answer provided by [Jacek Laskowski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44941909/8371915) (emphasis mine):

> If you have a beefy cluster with a plenty of RAM, **any size would work**. It's a tradeoff between network bandwidth and the available RAM.

it is much more complicated than amount of available RAM. With N workers, broadcasted dataset has to be transfered over network twice N + 1 times:

- Once to collect data to the driver (done transparently in broadcast joins).
- N times from the driver to the workers.

If broadcasted dataset is larger than 50% of the other dataset, network traffic will be larger than shuffling both datasets.

In practice bottleneck created by the driver network and some secondary costs (most notably serialization and GC) make broadcasting useless much faster.